# Correct way of upgrading with huge data

Tags: 7, nodes, updating

I have a Drupal 6 site that contains hundred of thousands of node and bunch of custom and contributed modules. My problem now is how can I upgrade this correctly in Drupal 7. I tried to steps presented in DrupalCon Denver which is a good steps for me, but I have a problem in converting the data when running update.php which stops the process.

Is there any good way to handle this case?

Comment: It is always possible that you detected a bug related to your amount of nodes or something else. Or maybe your memory limit or execution time limit is too low. Please provide more details than just "which stops the process". Do you get an error? WSOD? Check your error logs...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Option 1:

1. Inventory your 3rd party modules as well as your custom modules. Identify those modules that has a Drupal 7 version or if it's included in Drupal 7 core.
2. Update the Drupal 6 core.
3. Update the contrib modules and themes.
4. Disable contrib modules.
5. When everything is up-to-date and contrib modules are disabled, run update.php. This process will take time depending on how big is your database.
6. Enable your modules and start fixing some API that is not supported by Drupal 7. Use coder module to assist you.
7. Check, check, check.

Option 2:

1. Build from scratch.
2. Use migrate module to migrate you Drupal 6 db to Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

I have done upgrade of a Drupal website from 6.x to 7.x along with thousands of nodes migrated successfully to new one.

Drupal upgrade steps are listed in this link https://www.drupal.org/node/570162. I have followed these steps to make migrate successful.